# Sort list based on specific order in java

Tags: java, java-6

I have a list of object and need to sort it based on specific order. Something like below code:

```
preOrderedList = {"bmw","audi","benz"};
```

The list which comes from UI is carList `{"audi","benz","bmw"}`.

Problem here is user will be able to add a new row from application. Suppose if user adds a new row of "audi", then the carList will be like
 `{"audi","benz","bmw","audi"}`. In this case the list should be sorted like `{"bmw","audi","audi","benz"}.`

I have tried below code. It works only for without adding a new row, means `{"audi","benz","bmw"}`.

**That too while it gets sorts only the name("bmw","audi","benz") position is getting changed. I have one more field in Car class which is quantity. quantity will be in same position. This position should also get changed along with name.**

```
final List<String> preOrderedList = Arrays.asList("bmw","audi","benz");

Collections.sort(carList, new Comparator<Car>() {
        public int compare(Car l1, Car l2) {
            if (preOrderedList.contains(l1.getName().trim()) && preOrderedList.contains(l2.getName().trim())) {
                return preOrderedList.indexOf(l1.getName().trim()) - preOrderedList.indexOf(l2.getName().trim());
            }
            if (preOrderedList.contains(l1.getName().trim())) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (preOrderedList.contains(l2.getName().trim())) {
                return 1;
            }
            return l1.getName().trim().toString().compareTo(l2.getName().trim().toString());
        }
    });
```

I Expect the output as `{"bmw","audi","audi","benz"}` but my actual output is `{"bmw","audi","benz","audi"}.`

Comment: In what way is the list being sorted if you expect the output to be `{"bmw","audi","audi","benz"}`?

Comment: Based on the names which get matched with carList and preOrderedList

Comment: I would try TreeMap for which you can provide comparator method. It will keep your data in sorted order as you add more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be elegantly solved with [guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s `Ordering.explicit`:

```
Collections.sort(carList, Ordering.explicit(preOrderedList).onResultOf(new Function<Car, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Car car) {
        return car.getName();
    }
}));
```

The last version of Guava thas supports Java 6 is Guava 20.0:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Getting error: The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Car>, Ordering<String>)

Comment: @0991 I edited my answer

Comment: not working..order is getting changed.

Comment: @0991 What do you mean by "changed"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.